# On-prem docker swarm deployment with HA

Tags: docker, websocket, centos7, docker-swarm, high-availability

I’m doing on-prem deployments using docker swarm and I need application and DB high availability.

As far as **application HA** is concerned, it works great within docker (service discovery and load balancing), but I’m not sure how to use it on my network. I mean how can I assign a virtual IP to all of my docker managers so that if any of them goes down, that virtual IP automatically points to the other docker manager in the cluster. I don’t want to have a **single point of failure** in my architecture, that’s why I’m not inclined to use any (single) reverse proxy solution in front of my swarm cluster (because to my understanding, if nginx/HAProxy goes down, the whole system goes into abyss. I would love to know that I’m wrong).

Secondly, I use WebSockets in my application for push notifications which doesn’t behave normally with all the load balancing stuff because socket handshakes get distorted.

I want a solution to these problems without writing anything in code (HA-specific and non-generic like hard coding IPs etc). Any suggestions? I hope I explained my problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docker Flow Proxy](http://proxy.dockerflow.com/) or [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) can be placed on a set of swarm nodes that you want to receive traffic for incoming connections, and use DNS routing to get packets to the correct containers. Both have sticky sessions option (I know Docker Flow does, not sure about Traefik).

Then you can either:

1. If your incoming connections are just client HTTP/S requests, you can use DNS Round Robin with multiple A records, which works great, or
2. By an expensive hardware fault tolerant reverse proxy like F5
3. Use some network-layer IP failover that is at the OS and physical network level (not related to Docker really), but I'm not sure how well that would work with Swarm.

Number 2 is the typical solution in private datacenters that need full HA at all layers.

Comment: I've been researching and came across following:

**For 2:** [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) is an alternative. How well do you think it'd work?

**For 3:** I tried [keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/) on centos 7 to generate a VIP for all the swarm nodes. 
What's your take on that?

Comment: **As for 1** I'm thinking to try out [consul](https://www.consul.io/). I know I have to do only one of the three, but I wanna explore all the options. It would be great if the network or OS handles DNS mapping without any tool. I don't know how to do that.
My main concern here is the capability to automate the whole process with scalability and HA support, no matter what tools I use because I have to do a lot of on-prem deployments.

Comment: For sticky sessions, I'm gonna go with Traefik (it does have sticky sessions), but if I use a single traefik instance in front of the swarm, Doesn't it give a single point of failure in the system. If somehow, traefik crashes or the node crashes where traefik is deployed, my whole system would implode. Did I understand it right?
I might have to use multiple traefik instances or deploy it globally I guess.

Comment: Haproxy is great, and I prefer it. In the swarm i use Docker Flow Proxy to route incoming traffic, but outside the swarm you'd need some DNS failover or hardware HA to ensure incoming connection HA, regardless if you use Flow Proxy, Traefik, etc.